# "table doesn't exist" error with sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I am having problem with the database access in android.
First, I created an activity class for creating a table in the database.
Then I called that activity from another. Now on compiling I am stuck with an error that the table doesn't exists. Here is the code.

the first class is:-

```
package bivin.hello;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class main1 extends Activity {
      @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Intent i=new Intent();
        startActivity(i);
        SQLiteDatabase db;
        db=(SQLiteDatabase)openOrCreateDatabase("bivin.db",  SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY,null);

        Cursor cur=db.query("emp", null, null, null, null,null,null);
        db.beginTransaction();
        cur.moveToPosition(1);

      db.close();
```

and the calling activity is

```
package com.example.android.apis;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class createtable extends Activity
{
    public void onCreate(Bundle b)
    {
        super.onCreate(b);
        SQLiteDatabase db;
        db=openOrCreateDatabase("bivin.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
        db.execSQL("create table emp(name text,password text;");
        ContentValues c=new ContentValues();
        c.put("name", "Bivin");
        c.put("password", "Ravindran");

        db.insert("emp",null,c);
        db.close();
        }
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: i just wanted to create a database table from one activity and access it from another.

Comment: `createtable.onCreate` runs before `main1.onCreate`? It will fail if this is not the case.

Comment: no here  main1.onCreate runs first. Can you please tell me the reason just a bit confused :-).

Comment: Is creating the table in the database the only thing that your 'createtable' Activity does? If so it's the wrong use for an Activity. The Activity class in Android is designed to provide a UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its obvious, createtable onCreate should be executed before main1's onCreate. The table is being created later, hence the error

Answer (score 0):

your datatype is wrong use varchar instread of text

```
SQLiteDatabase sampleDB = null;
String PhoneNumber;
String UserId;
Cursor c;
ArrayList ar=new ArrayList();
public void createDatabse(String DbName,Context context)
{

    sampleDB =  context.openOrCreateDatabase(DbName, context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE,null);

}

public void createUserIdTable(String Tablename,Context context)
{
    sampleDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
            Tablename +
            " (User_Id VARCHAR);");

}

public void insertDataUser(String tableName,String User_Id)
{

     sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
             tableName +
             " Values ('"+User_Id+"');");


}

public String GetUserData(Context context,String tablename)
{
            c = sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT User_Id FROM " +
                tablename +
                "", null);

            if(c!=null)
            {
                if(c.moveToFirst())
                {
                    do
                    {
                        UserId=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("User_Id"));

                    }while(c.moveToNext());



                    }   

                }       

            return UserId;
}

public void close()
{
    sampleDB.close();

}
```